# Is it possible to start every Appium test with same initial state of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, automation, appium

The iOS app that I am writing automation for, waits for 5 minutes before doing an activity and there are lot of cases I need to test when the 5 minutes are over. Is it possible to advance the app state to say 4 minutes and 15 seconds and then have every Appium test start from this point onwards so that overall my test suite runs faster - akin to having a save and restore state kind of facility? The default fullReset option is for a different purpose. Is there a way out?

thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You setting capability `noReset` to `true` will help?

Comment: Hi @Jakub, my understanding was that the noReset flag helps to avoid app installs before each test, can it be used to restore to a saved state, and start over again from that checkpoint dropping off any state transitions that happened after the checkpoint?

Comment: This won't work. Setting `noReset` to `true` would mean that you'd continue from the app's previous state. If you've already advanced past the 5 minute wait state, you would again open up the app past the 5 minute wait state.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a snapshot of the app state. From my understanding, this is not possible - so you're going to have to wait the full duration every time.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in most cases you don't wait X amount of time rather than wait for activity to happen - Sometime the way to approach it is to wait constant time assuming that by then the operation will end. I usually try to understand how i can validate that the action ended - E.g. check the back-end or DB status - Than you can build a function that wait until the status is ready for the next step.

Comment: Let me explain my case, my app waits for 5 minutes before posting activity details to server. So to test various scenarios of activity posting, I have to run every such test in isolation so that the activity log is cleared after the 5 minutes post to server and the log is now empty. If I run the tests in parallel, an activity from another test can enter the activity log history and asserting for expected results will become messier. Hope I am clear.